# update record entity api

Tags: entities

Im using entity api. How to update record in entity api

i have:

```
class ExampleTaskController extends EntityAPIController {

  public function create(array $values = array()) {
    global $user;
    $values += array(
       'title' => '',
       'description' => '',
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'uid' => $user->uid,
    );
     return parent::create($values);
  }
```

Then:

```
$task = entity_create('ExampleTask', array('description' => "alamakota");
entity_create($task);
```

if my task have id=1 how to perform update on record? I want change 'description' to 'newtext' in record with id =1

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) The duplicate refers specifically to nodes, but the principle is the same for any entity type so you can use any of the methods outlined in the accepted answer

Comment: I have seen it before but this is not an answer working in drupal7. Now i have solution it is:

Comment: I;m not sure what you mean, the other answers are for Drupal 7 _only_ (they won't work with Drupal 6). I use those methods 20 times a day, they're definitely correct.

Comment: I have seen it before but this is not an answer working in drupal7. Now i have solution it is: 
   
   $node = reset(entity_load('ExampleTask', array(2)));
    $node->'description' ='newtext' ;
    $node->save();
  
  The diffrence is that you have to use array [array(1)] === [id =1],  not an id direct
  In answer You provided Id is direct. And one thing more im not in hook_method, im in form submit...

Comment: Again, not sure what you mean I'm afraid, the code in your previous comment can't possibly work because the object returned from `entity_load()` is a `stdClass` and doesn't have a `save()` method. If you're using `save()`, you simply must be using the `EntityMetadataWrapper` method, as in the accepted answer to the other question. Unless your entity controller has something custom on it, but that still doesn't invalidate the other answers, which are definitely accurate.

Comment: Thanks Clive for help, its working as i pointed really. `entity_load()`  returns table of results thats why `reset` is nessesery to get first object